# Projection of a non-surjective operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Apologies for the poor title.

What I'm wondering is:
Say that we have a non-surjective operator $A:X\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is a Banach space, and the operator is defined in terms of the basis vectors $ê_i$:
$$
A(x)=\sum\limits_{i,k=1}^\infty\alpha_{i,k}\cdot x_{k}\cdotê_i=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{y_k\cdotê_k}
$$
edit: where there are countably many $i$ for which $\alpha_{i,k}$ is non-zero for some $k$.

A <strike>restriction</strike> projection of the operator is:
$$
A'(x)=\sum\limits_{i\in I,k=1}^\infty\alpha_{i,k}\cdot x_{k}\cdotê_i=\sum\limits_{k\in I}{y_k\cdotê_k}
$$
Where $I$ is a finite index set.

Given $y=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{y_k\cdotê_k}$ that is not in the image of $A$, is it always possible to take such a projection in a way so that the finite set of linear equations you get don't have a solution?

If one of the basis vector isn't in the image it's easy to realise that you can, for example the right shift operator:$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,...) \rightarrow (0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,...)$$

My next thought was that there has to be a basis vector not in the image, because otherwise the image would span $X$ but I don't think that's enough.

This isn't a homework problem, it's just something that's been distracting me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a projection, not a restriction.

The answer is no.  For example, on $\ell^2$ consider the non-surjective operator
$(T x)_n = x_n/n$.

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my question as I posed it, but I realise I forgot to mention that I was thinking about the case where $\alpha_{i,k}$ is non-zero for countably many $i$. To put it more crudely, where the operator $A$ is defined by a system countably many linear equations but the projection (as you say) only has finitely many. I should update the question.